# Passing value to Switch activity

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I need to pass value from my custom activity to the Switch activity without using workflow variables.

Also, i dont want to create my own custom Switch activity to do this.

I hope this is possible

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only way to pass data between two activities in a workflow is either to use workflow variables or In/Out arguments.
Why do you have this constraint no to use workflow variables?
Also which version of WF are you using?

**EDIT:**
Custom `ActivityDesigner` can set up workflow variables for you. So if you need one for your first custom activity and another linked to the default `Switch` activity.
In this case users don't set up variables, they only need to select a variable from a list for the switch.

Comment: cause im rehosting workflow designer so that my customer can use it and i want to simplify creation of workflow as much as possible. Version is 4.0

Comment: In this case you can try to create a custom ActivityDesigner plus defining your custom activity to return result. Then you ActivityDesigner can ask the user which activity's result to use for the switch.  In theory this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the effort ViktorZ but im going to wait for some other answer to come. i didnt want to create custom activity or to use variables at all. If its possible i want to transfer value to Expression field of Switch activity just by connecting them

Comment: Sure. I am very interested in the outcome. In my team we where trying to use WF Designer outside of VS2010, but felt a bit disappointed and decided to create a custom graphical editor for workflows. But that's another story :)